# Powershell multiple credential setup

Tags: windows, powershell, credentials

I just setup a *powershell* to collect disk space info among a group of servers.
but I encounter an issue that while I try to authenticate from one server to another, it require different credential info.

E.g.
SQLServer01

> ID: domain1\sqladmin1
>
> PW: 123456

SQLServer02

> ID: domain2\sqladmin2
>
> PW: 654321

right now i manage to setup first one with limited power-shell experience.

```
$comp= Get-Content "C:\disk_info\Computers.txt"
$diskvalue = @()
#$cre = get-Credential

$username = "domain1\sqladmin1"
$password = "123456"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $secureStringPwd



foreach($pc in $comp)
{
    $diskvalue += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $pc -credential $creds -Filter DriveType=3 | 
    Select SystemName , DeviceID , @{Name=”size(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.size/1gb)}}, @{Name=”freespace(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.freespace/1gb)}}, @{Name=”UsedSpace(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N2}” -f(($_.size - $_.FreeSpace)/1gb)}}
    #$diskvalue -replace ":",""
    $diskvalue | Export-Csv C:\disk_info\DiskReport.csv -NoTypeInformation
    
}
```

Yet I am trying to input another credential for some servers only. `domain2\` in this case.

Computer.txt as reference

```
sqlserver1.domain1.com 
sqlserver2.domain1.domain2.com 
sqlserver3.domain1.com
```

the one including "domain2" would be the need of multiple credential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the full qualified domain names for the machine in `Computers.txt`, you could use a simple `if` statement to decide which domain credentials to use. You will just need to change the `$domain2Match` variable at the top to your 2nd domain in the below script (`$domain2Match='.domain1.domain2.com'`).

```
$comp= Get-Content "C:\disk_info\Computers.txt"
$diskvalue = @()

# Put your FQDN without the server name here for the seconded domain
$domain2Match = '.domain1.domain2.com' 

# Credential 1
$username = "domain1\sqladmin1"
$password = "123456"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $secureStringPwd

# Credential 2   
$username2 = "domain2\sqladmin2"
$password2 = "123456"
$secureStringPwd2 = $password2 | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$creds2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user2, $secureStringPwd2


foreach($pc in $comp)
{
    $credsToUse = $null

    If($pc -imatch $domain2Match){
        # Matched use domain 2 Credential
        $credsToUse = $creds2 
    }Else {
        # No match use domain 1 Credential
        $credsToUse = $creds
    }

    $diskvalue += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $pc -credential $credsToUse -Filter DriveType=3 | 
    Select SystemName , DeviceID , @{Name=”size(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.size/1gb)}}, @{Name=”freespace(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.freespace/1gb)}}, @{Name=”UsedSpace(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N2}” -f(($_.size - $_.FreeSpace)/1gb)}}
    $diskvalue | Export-Csv C:\disk_info\DiskReport.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: since my domain name were different while login and the computer address. 
e.g. address1.address2.com - domain machine address
e.g. address1 - login domain address in the front. \

Comment: @D.chan Could you update you question with your text file example, so I can see that you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two Credenital Objects:

### Cred 1

```
$username = "domain1\sqladmin1"
$password = "123456"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $secureStringPwd
```

### Cred 2

```
$username = "domain2\sqladmin2"
$password = "123456"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$creds2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $secureStringPwd
```

Then use an IF Statement along with splatting Params (will be easier and cleaner)

```
foreach($pc in $comp)
{

$Params = @{
Class = "Win32_logicaldisk"
ComputerName = $pc
Credential = $creds
Filter = 'DriveType=3' 
}

If ($pc -eq "SQLServer02")
{
$Params["Credential"] = $creds2
}
    $diskvalue += Get-WmiObject @Params | Select SystemName , DeviceID , @{Name=”size(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.size/1gb)}}, @{Name=”freespace(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N1}” -f($_.freespace/1gb)}}, @{Name=”UsedSpace(GB)”;Expression={“{0:N2}” -f(($_.size - $_.FreeSpace)/1gb)}}
    #$diskvalue -replace ":",""
    $diskvalue | Export-Csv C:\disk_info\DiskReport.csv -NoTypeInformation

  }
```

Comment: If ($pc -eq "SQLServer02")
i notice the above statement will only apply to -eq "SQLServer02", what if i got more then server require creds2 ?

Comment: simply add an "OR" parameter between ?

Comment: create array of computers. `$PCArray = @("SQLServer02","SQLServer03","SQLServer04")` then change the if statement to: `If ($PCArray -contains $pc) {$Params["Credential"] = $creds2}`