# How to run multiple cmd command using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I want to login with different user credential and run multiple cmd command.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: do you REALLY need to use ps2 & ps3 _along with azure powershell_? if not, PLEASE, remove the unneeded tags.

Comment: also, please read the tour page for this site to understand the rules you are breaking ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

For running multiple command using powershell, you can use **PowerShell ISE**. Actually this tool is installed already in Windows System, and you can use it directly. If you don't have this tool, get it from [here](https://winaero.com/blog/install-or-uninstall-windows-powershell-ise-in-windows-10/).
[image]

For login with different user credential, if you are talking about different azure account, just do `Connect-AzAccount` again with another account.

I would recommend you open another powershell terminal to login with different user.

Comment: I want to login in cmd with different user credential and then run 2-3 command in cmd. How can I create powershell script for this. It's not through powershell to through file

Comment: Did this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953487/powershell-multiple-credential-setup